# str.replaceAll() not matching "\r\n"

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert Unix-style line-endings (`LF`) in a multi-line string to Windows-style (`CR LF`).

My plan of attack is to:

- replace all `CR LF` instances with just `LF`
- then replace all `LF` instances with `CR LF`

However, this snippet of code isn't matching the `"\r\n"`:

```
String test = "test\r\ncase";
test.replaceAll("\r\n","\n");

PrintWriter testFile = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
testFile.print(test);
testFile.close();
```

I've already tried using double/triple/quadruple backslashes. No dice.

I also know that the `test` string doesn't contain a literal `\r\n` because it detects them as `CR LF` when printing to file.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that the first input argument to `replaceAll` is supposed to be a regular expression. You should probably use `"[\r\n]+"` or something similar (perhaps `"(\r\n|\r|\n)"`).

Comment: @barakmanos so what should it be then? I've already tried double-backslashing but to no avail

Comment: No, backslashes are not the point here. With a double backslash, you're essentially telling the `replaceAll` function to look for a backslash. You need to give the first argument as a proper regular expression.

Comment: replaceAll **return** the new String, it does not change `test` because String are immutable. So even if you add used the correct method, you never saved the value

Comment: Yes!!! That's the correct answer (which I didn't even notice). Should be `test = test.replaceAll("\r\n","\n");`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/109/strings

Comment: Why was this question down-voted??? It is well constructed and explained. An effort is demonstrated. All relevant details are provided. Are people not allowed to ask legitimate questions here anymore???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not gettign the modified String from your code.

**String are immutable** so you need to save the returned value from `replaceAll`. There is no method that can change an instance of `String`

```
String test = "test\r\ncase";

//Print the character before
for(char c : test.toCharArray()){ System.out.print((int)c + " ");};
System.out.println();

//Save the replace result
test = test.replaceAll("\r\n","\n");

//Print the character after
for(char c : test.toCharArray()){ System.out.print((int)c + " ");};
```

Show that the test is first not changed then changed

```
116 101 115 116 13 10 99 97 115 101 //BEFORE
116 101 115 116 10 99 97 115 101    //AFTER
```